# How to check for RateLimitException error with Stichoza GoogleTranslate?

Tags: laravel-8, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have been using Stichoza GoogleTranslate for days with no problem.  Suddenly I got the RateLimitException error.  I want to test for that error in Laravel php before it stops the script.

Here is the function I am using :

```
 // function GoogleTranslate
 function translate($tr,$text,$target,$source='en-GB') {
      // check for error i.e. RateLimitException
      if (0) {
           $trans = $tr->setSource($source)->setTarget($target)->translate($text);
      } else {
           $trans = $text;
      }
      return $trans;
 }
```

How can I do that?

I also tried to use a proxy as advised but then got an error...

```
 $trans = $tr->setOptions(['proxy' => 'tcp://localhost:8090'])->setSource($source)->setTarget($target)->translate($text);

  cURL error 7: Unsupported proxy scheme for 'tcp://localhost:8090' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&hl=en&dt=t&dt=bd&dt=at&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&sl=en-GB&tl=da&q=Sustainability+Code+of+Conduct+%28for+travellers%29&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&otf=0&pc=1&trs=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=345571.226973
```

My intention is to use Stichoza first if no error detected, then google cloud translate.  Now I am just bypassing the translation (as above).

Is this the way to catch the error

```
try {
    $trans = $tr->setSource($source)->setTarget($target)->translate($text);
} catch (RateLimitException $e) {
    report($e);
    //$trans = GoogleCloudTranslation($text); // to be checked
}
```

Comment: try {} catch is suitable?

Comment: @Maksim I have never use that before... Is my update correct?